# Angular life-cycle sequence between parents and child components

Tags: angular, angular-lifecycle-hooks

I have onInit on parent that does massaging of data that will be the input of child component. And the input is used in child’s onInit to be passed to a service. It is working fine when I put break point on child’s onInit, the input is already massaged and what I want.
But does this mean first it does all the parent’s lifecycle then child’s lifecycle?
If I put breakpoints, it goes like.. parent onInit -> child onChanges -> child onInit. And this is the order that I want but I just wanted to make sure this is the always the case otherwise I might need to move the data massage logic to the constructor of the parent.

Comment: please check this documentation : https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-sequence

Comment: @JoelJoseph, Thank you for the response but I'm asking about timing related to parent and child components not just single component.  The doc is only explaining about single component lifecycle.